# How do I enable JS library auto completion in PhpStorm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, configuration, autocomplete, phpstorm

In an HTML file, I included jQuery via

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

I downloaded the library via the context menu and now see it in the project folder under `External Libraries`. Yet, it seems jQuery is not recognized.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    ..
    });
</script>
```

The `$` is underlined and code hinting asks me to create a function or method called `$`. The code itself works though.

What am I supposed to do to make PhpStorm recognize the external JavaScript library?

Comment: Works fine here (in the document where script was defined). Please check "Settings | JavaScript | Libraries" -- you may need to add that library to a bigger scope (by default that library will be allowed for that file only) -- use "Manage Scopes" for that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As LazyOne pointed out in his comment I had to look up settings, and there I realized I had to download the library again, and made it global.

[image: phpstorm's settings]

Comment: You can avoid having to manually set the library options by using the 'Download' button on the right. jQuery and jQuery-UI are both listed under the official libraries. Choose either then click 'Download and Install' to have the library automatically added to the global scope.